# When listview item is clicked display an image

Tags: android, image, listview, display

I'm making an app which will display an image once an item from the listView will be clicked. At the moment it only shows a TOAST where it tells you what user you chose and what position he/she is at.

Here is my mainActivity code:

```
package com.example.listviewdemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter aAdapter;
    private String[] users = { "John", "Mary", "George", "Lisa", "Sarah", "Ben"};
    ImageView image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_selected_image);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlist);
        aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, users);
        mListView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                String user = users[position];
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + user + ", "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the XML for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/J"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ECDBDB">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/John"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/John" />
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem you face?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to display an image once a user is clicked from the user list. But I do not know how to go about it

Comment: please share your adapter code